# How to enter to chat section

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I want to discuss my technical and coding related problems with users on stackoverflow.
How can I chat with individual user to discuss my problem?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ <--

Comment: @MartijnPieters Read the OP. He asked about Stack Overflow.

Comment: @qwertynl: Ah, I only saw where it was migrated from. :-P

Comment: @gnat I think the user is asking how to start chat with a specific user, not chat in general.

Answer (score 0):

There **used to** be a link on top to go to chat.

I guess new users do not know it used to be there, so [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) is the link for chat

Comment: The link is in the site dropdown.

Comment: Yea.. It is a little hard to find for new users @Oded The old top bar had it explicitly.